# If $\gamma\in \Bbb A$ then there exists a $\pm$quadratic coefficiented polynomial for which $\gamma$ is a root.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, roots

$\mathbf{1.\space Proposition}$

> Let $\gamma$ be a solution to the equation:
>
> $$
> \sum_{i=0}^n \rm a_i\rm x^i=0, \rm a_i\in\Bbb Z, a_n=1.
> $$
>
> Then, there exists a polynomial $p\in \Bbb Z[x]$ such that:
>   $$
> p=\sum _{i=0}^m\rm s_ix^i
> $$
>
> Where $\rm s_i=(-1)^{k_i}\tau_i^2 \space\space\forall \rm i\in \{0,..,m\}, k_i\in \Bbb Z, \tau_i\in \Bbb Z$, for which $\gamma$ is a root.

$\mathbf{1.1\space Generalization}$.

> There exist a monic polynomial satisfying the above conditions.

$\mathbf{1.2\space Generalization}$

> Same conditions as $\rm1$, but $\rm s_i=(-1)^{k_i}\tau_i^r$, for all natural $\rm r$.

$\mathbf{1.3\space Generalization}$

> There exists a monic polynomial satisfying $\rm1.2$.

$\mathbf{Important \space implication \space of \space 1.1 }$

> If $\rm 1.1$ is true, it means that the condition of $\gamma$ being the root of a monic polynomial $p\in \Bbb Z[x]$ is actually equivalent to the 'stronger' condition of being a solution to a $\pm$quadratic coefficiented polynomial $q\in \Bbb Z[x]$.

Comment: that's a very strange question. I don't expect anyone to know.

Comment: Are you asking if, for any algebraic integer $\alpha$, there exists a polynomial whose coefficients are (perhaps $\pm$?) perfect squares that has $\alpha$ as a root?

Comment: Yes, pjs, you got it.

Comment: Do you still want the polynomial to me monic?

Comment: Can you find such an equation for $\sqrt3$ ?

Comment: @quid No, not necessarily, although it would be nice to know if this is possible with monic polynomials.

Comment: $(x^4-9)$ works for $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: You can always do it for $\sqrt[n]{m}$ since the polynomial $x^{2n}-m^2=(x^n-m)(x^n+m)$ will work...but for more complicated things, I have no idea.

Comment: Could you write $1+\sqrt5$ in this manner ?

Comment: @Lucian Yes, you could do $x^4-4x^2-16x-16=(x^2-2x-4)(x^2+2x+4)$, or, alternatively, you could even just do $4x^2-8x-16$. One I'm not sure about is $1+i\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @BenS.: Then the answer to the OP's question is *yes*. Try $x^4-4x^3+4x^2-9$.

Comment: @Lucian Good point...but what about for the roots of something like $x^3+2x^2+3x-7$?

Comment: @BenS.: Sorry. Apparently, I had a different understanding of algebraic integers. In which case, I have no idea.

Comment: Editted post for clarity. @BenS. Damn, that polynomial has some ugly roots...

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Note that your claim is equivalent to: "Given a monic polynomial $m(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, does there exist a polynomial $q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that the coefficients of $m(x)q(x)$ are squares?" This allows you to write out a system of linear equations, on the coefficients, and by choosing the degree of $q(x)$ large enough, you might be able to prove there is a solution involving perfect squares...or perhaps discover a way of getting a counterexample?

Comment: Thanks @BenS., after setting up the equations I wasn't able to deduce a 'systematic' way of even trying to find a counterexample. This seems to be a surprisingly harder problem than I thought.

Comment: @BenS.: (1) $4x^2-8x-16$ is not allowed $-$ $8$ is not a perfect square. (2) Are you sure that OP's claim is equivalent to what you say? I think it has to be "given a monic polynomial $m(x)$ _irreducible over_ $\mathbb Z[x]$". The OP only requires that $\gamma$ be a root of $p$, not that $p$ be a multiple of $\Sigma a_ix^i$.

Comment: @TonyK Before the question was edited, I interpreted it to be asking for a polynomial with every coefficient a power of some number, but not necessarily the same power. In any case, $x^4-4x^2-16x-16$ still works in that example. And I had a typo. I meant the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: @BenS.: Then I think your statement needs to be completely rephrased. The current version has no mention of $\gamma$, so what is $m(x)$ the minimal polynomial of?

Comment: @TonyK $\gamma$ could be any algebraic integer. Let $m(x)$ be its minimal polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then we need a polynomial $p(x)$ so that $m(x)p(x)$ has coefficients which are squares (or cubes, or whatever case we are looking at). This is the same as not specifying $\gamma$, but instead looking at all monic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and asking if for each one, there is some $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ so that $m(x)p(x)$ has coefficients which are squares.

Comment: @BenS.: But that's exactly what I said! If I may be allowed to quote myself: "given a monic polynomial $m(x)$ _irreducible_ over $\mathbb Z[x]$". It wasn't a typo on your part, it was a braino.

Comment: @TonyK Yes...but you may as well just think of all monic polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, since you are multiplying by another polynomial $p(x)$ anyway. So irreducible monic and monic in this case give you a statement which is still equivalent to the original.

Comment: Re 1.1 By monic do you mean with leading co-efficient equal to 1? If so, it is impossible with $\gamma =2/3$ although I dk what can be said about  non-rational $\gamma$.

Comment: Bounty expiring ;o.

Answer (score 1):

> **Proposition**: Let $\gamma$ be an algebraic integer, $r$ an odd positive integer. Then there exists a non-zero polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $r$-power coefficients such that $f(\gamma)=0$.

This is a consequence of Birch's theorem on odd-degree forms over number fields in many variables. We will need the following special case of Birch's theorem.

> **Theorem (Birch)**: Let $k$ and $r$ be postive integers, with $r$ odd. Then there exists a positive integer $n$ such that, if $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ are homogeneous polynomials with integer coefficients in $n$ variables, there exists $\vec{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\neq (0,\ldots,0)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $f_1(\vec{x})=\ldots=f_k(\vec{x})=0$.

*Proof of proposition*: We are given $\gamma$ and odd $r$. Let $k=\deg(\gamma)$, and let $n$ be as in the conclusion of Birch's Theorem. Choose an integral basis $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\gamma]$. For each $m\geq 0$, there are unique integers $a_{m,1},\ldots,a_{m,k}$ such that $\gamma^m=a_{m,1}\alpha_1+\ldots+a_{m,k}\alpha_k$. For $i=1,\ldots,k$, define
$$
f_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=a_{1,i}x_1^r+\ldots+a_{n,i}x_n^r.
$$
The $f_i$ are $k$ homogeneous polynomial of degree $r$ in $n$ variables, so by Birch's theorem, they have a common non-zero solution $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Now
$$
x_1^r\gamma+x_2^r\gamma^2+\ldots+x_n^r\gamma^n=0,
$$
as desired.